# 'High quality' or 'high-quality'?

Tags: conjunctions, punctuation

For the longest time, I have seen and written 'high quality' as such. However, Grammarly just dropped this bombshell on me;

[image]

Is that correct? My copy of Grammarly is set to British English as that is where I live, but I don't think I've ever seen this phrase written with a dash.

Answer (score 8):

As a compound adjective "**[high-quality](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/high-quality)**" means "**of very good quality**" and is written with a hyphen:

- Consumers are trading up from stores' own brands to **high-quality garments**.

On the other hand if "**quality**" is a noun then no hyphen is required:

- Consumers are trading up from stores' own brands to **garments of high quality**.